# Set the background color of selected text in NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, highlight, nstextview

I am trying to change the background color of a portion of text that is selected by the user to a different color (to add a highlight) to the text. Now I have tried the:

- (void)setSelectedTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes

method but that only changes the background color of the selection. I need the to change the background color of text so that it stays highlighted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing text selection color in NSTextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300272/changing-text-selection-color-in-nstextview)

Comment: Not a dup. That refers to changing the color of the highlight (when the text is selected) and does not keep the background color once the selection has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, the selected text attributes only apply to the text while it's selected. If you want to add some attributes to the selected text that persist, you'll need to apply those attributes to the underlying `NSTextStorage` object (which is just a subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString`).

The way to do that is to use the text view's [`textStorage`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000373-BBCECDIB) method and then apply the attributes using the [`addAttributes:range:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000169-addAttributes_range_) method (or `setAttributes:range:` depending on whether you want to add to the existing text attributes or replace them altogether).