# Swift - Get color from selected text in NSTextView

Tags: swift, text, colors, selection, nstextview

I want to check whether or no a range of a selected text is coloured in Red in my NSTextView. I know that it conforms to NSText class and there is a textColor property in NSText but I can't get the color for my NSRange selection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's how to [Set the background color of selected text in NSTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4926171/4244136). Getting the foreground color is similar. Get `textStorage` and enumerate the attribute.

Comment: How do i enumerate the attribute?

Comment: Use `NSAttributedString`s enumeration methods.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the property `selectedTextAttributes` of `NSTextView` ([documented here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstextview/1449270-selectedtextattributes))

```
let selectedTextAttributes = textview.selectedTextAttributes
if let foregroundColor = selectedTextAttributes[NSForegroundColorAttributeName] as? NSColor {
    //Here is your foreground color
}
```

Hope that helps.

### Update

As @willeke points out in the comment below my "answer here" won't do the trick. Have a look at his comment to the original question instead.

Comment: "The attributes used to indicate the selection." isn't the same as the attributes of the text which is selected.

Comment: @Willeke thanks for the info, I guess I spoke to soon then. I'll leave the answer here though...just so other people does not make the same mistake. Once again thanks for clarifying :)